# Why logLik works for PLM models in R?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, aic, likelihood

I'm estimating linear panel models with fixed effects in R using plm of the plm-package. As I was looking for ways to compare different models, I came across AIC (Akaike's ‘An Information Criterion’). AIC of the stats-package works according to the documentation for model objects for which a log-likelihood value can be obtained. According to the comments given the OLS-estimator of a linear model is the maximum likelihood estimator. But is this also true for fixed-effects panel models (within-estimator)?
Here is a minimal example:

```
data("Produc", package = "plm")
zz <- plm::plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, model="pooling",
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
yy <- plm::plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, model="within",
          data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
stats::logLik(zz)
stats::logLik(yy)
stats::AIC(zz)
stats::AIC(yy)
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Under the standard assumptions when you do inference on OLS models (including normal errors), the usual $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ is the maximum likelihood estimator.

Comment: @Dave OLS is MLE, but I'm not sure about PLM. Suggested edit to body and title.

Comment: @Dave: That makes perfectly sence, thank you for your input. Could somebody add on the comment of AdamO? I will adjust my question.

Comment: What AdamO said potentially makes my comment unhelpful. What I wrote is true but may not apply. I do not know if the estimator used by this software is the MLE.

Comment: Does this actually work for you though? 
I always get the error: `Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"`

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking to actually calculate the `logLik` for a `plm` object, consider this, which comes from a Stack Overflow question on the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186453/r-extract-log-likelihood-from-a-plm-object/65278944#65278944).

`object` here is a plm object, like `zz` above.

```r
logLik.plm <- function(object){
  out <- -plm::nobs(object) * log(2 * var(object$residuals) * pi)/2 - deviance(object)/(2 * var(object$residuals))
  
  attr(out,"df") <- nobs(object) - object$df.residual
  attr(out,"nobs") <- plm::nobs(object)
  return(out)
}
```

Once this is defined, this should then also work with the `AIC` command:

```r
data("Produc", package = "plm")
zz <- plm::plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, model="pooling",
               data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
yy <- plm::plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp, model="within",
               data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))


logLik.plm <- function(object){
  out <- -plm::nobs(object) * log(2 * var(object$residuals) * pi)/2 - deviance(object)/(2 * var(object$residuals))
  
  attr(out,"df") <- nobs(object) - object$df.residual
  attr(out,"nobs") <- plm::nobs(summary(object))
  return(out)
}

stats::logLik(zz)
[1] 826.9814
attr(,"df")
[1] 5
attr(,"nobs")
[1] 816

stats::logLik(yy)
[1] 1534.531
attr(,"df")
[1] 52
attr(,"nobs")
[1] 816

stats::AIC(zz)
[1] -1643.963

stats::AIC(yy) 
[1] -2965.063
```

I have created a public gist [here](https://gist.github.com/moritzpschwarz/35fc5be900b99a1a593ab5dd7018ff7b).